# I am having problem with the django and constantly getting error i.e. "local variable 'form' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I am having this error `local variable 'form' referenced before assignment`. I am not sure what's wrong with the code . The `form` does not load and the if the `form` is assigned to different variable and used then the page loaded but the form does not **load.**

My **model.py:**

```
from django.db.models.aggregates import Max
from django.db.models.base import Model
from django.db.models.fields import CharField

# Create your models here.

class Work(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='workimages/')
    summary =models.CharField(max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, null=True)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null= True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**view.py:**

```
from .models import *
from .forms import *
# Create your views here.
def home (request):
    work = Work.objects.all()

    if request.method ==  "POST":
        form = Contactform(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()


    context ={ 'work':work,'form':form}
    return render(request, 'mysite/index.html',context)
```

**index.html:**

```
  <form method="POST">

    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row margin-bottom-small center-xs">

        <div class="col-md padding-small">
            {{ form }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md padding-small">
            <!-- <textarea placeholder="Your Message" name="" rows="8"
                class="margin-bottom-small"></textarea> -->
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </div>

 </form>
```

**forms.py**:

```
from django import forms
from django.db.models import fields
from django.forms.forms import Form
from django.forms.models import ModelForm
from django.db import models
from .models import *

class Contactform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        models = Contact
        fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put **else** condition.

```
    from .models import *
    from .forms import *
    def home(request):
        work = Work.objects.all()
    
        if request.method ==  "POST":
            form = Contactform(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
        else:            
            form = Contactform()
    
        context ={ 'work':work,'form':form}
        return render(request, 'mysite/index.html',context)
```

---

or without **else** condition:

```
    from .models import *
    from .forms import *
    def home(request):
        work = Work.objects.all()
        
        form = Contactform(request.POST or None)
        if request.method ==  "POST":
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
        context ={'work':work,'form':form}
        return render(request, 'mysite/index.html',context)
```

Comment: it does not work still the same error comes

Comment: @JER can you share your **error traceback** screen-shot?

Comment: I have solved the problem, what i actually need to do was to declare the form= ContactForm(request.POST or none) before the if statement. The error occured beacaue the content in the form variable was to be accessed but the access was denied beacause it was inside the post statement. Anyways thanks for the help

Comment: @JER ohh!! I forgot to tell you..See my ans. second way..

Comment: thats the answer to the problem. Thanks man